# Trying get case object with specific id but that object data not retrived

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I want get case object for perticular id so for that I have used below API

https://service-now.com/api/sn_customerservice/case/CS0001052

so before some time of period it's working fine and gave expected responce.
but now it gives responce
{
"error": {
"message": "No Record found",
"detail": ""
},
"status": "failure"
}

So I verified the ID with object present on servicenow UI. but still responce comming "No Record found".
I have try with verious ID's but still issue is there. so anybody can help me to sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The account that you are using to authenticate through the API possibly doesn't have access to that record. Even if the record really exists, if that account doesn't have access it'll show as "record not found".